# View Shared Folders on a Mapped Drive

Tags: .net, windows, networking, batch-file, cmd

So I want to view all the shared folders on a mapped network drive. I know you can use:

```
net share
```

in command prompt to view the shared folders on your local drive. And I've tried the below to try to view the shared folders in my my mapped drive, L:\

```
L:\ cd\
net share
```

But that again only the shared folders in my local drive are shown.

Searched around the internet for a while and couldn't find anything. This [forum](http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/354853-how-to-view-network-shared-folders-on-remote-system-like-mapped-drives) has a similar question but none of them seem to get it right really.

If there is any way to do this using .Net I would accept that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the computer hosting the files knows which folders are shared. (Try sharing a folder on that mapped drive.)

In order to do this the Correct Way™, you'll have to run the process (`net share`) on the machine actually serving the directory you have mapped to L:.

I believe Windows stores share information in the registry:
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\LanmanServer\Shares`

If you knew the machine name serving the share you've mapped to L: (we'll call it server-32), then you could do something like

```
REG QUERY \\server-32\HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\LanmanServer\Shares
```

This doesn't show you any of the admin shares (`IPC$`, `C$`, etc.), but it will show you the items that have been shared by users.

Answer (score 1):

simply

```
net view \\COMPUTERNAME
```

Comment: This will display only non-hidden shares.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers this might be, but the accepted answer `reg query \\COMPUTERNAME...` doesn't work here (_network path not found_).

Comment: Both commands use MS directory services. Unless remote registry services is turned off, I would expect both to work or fail the same.